# How to combine (add?) 2 same dimension matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I am sure there's a really easy way to do this but been having trouble with it. I essentially have two matrices that are 8 by 8. They both have different data but also a lot of blanks (NA). The way the data is generated there won't be different answers in the same cell across the matrices so basically if there is data in a cell in matrix 1 then that same cell is na in matrix 2. Here is some code to generate these types of matrices for example:

```
matrix1 <-structure(list(X1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA), X2 = c(NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), X3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), X4 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), X5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
   NA_real_, NA_real_), X6 = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0), X7 = c(1, 
      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
             NA)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8"
                              ), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

matrix2 <- structure(list(X1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA), X2 = c(NA, 
                 NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0), X3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), X4 = c(1, 
                   1, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA), X5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), X6 = c(1, 
                     NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA), X7 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                      NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), X8 = c(NA, 
                       0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", 
                     "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to combine these matrices into one 8 by 8 matrix that has the data points from both these matrices still in an 8 by 8 format. Most everything I tried just ends up with a matrix with all na but there should be some easy way to do this I just can't figure out. If you know of a way to do that please let me know and thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You don't have to change the title to say "[Solved]". Simply accept (there is a check under the arrows) @akrun's answer and it will appear to others as solved. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `pmin` (assuming the non-NA position don't overlap)

```
pmin(matrix1, matrix2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or another option is `coalesce` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
coalesce(matrix1, matrix2)
```